# XML Requests works in SOAPUI-5.6.0 but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, pycharm, soapui

I am able to successfully run an XML request in SOAPUI-5.6.0, but the same XML, using the requests module, does not work in python.

Python Code is as follows

```
import requests
api_url = "https://testing2.tracker.com/services/webservices.asmx"
xml_file = "CreateorUpdateTask3"

with open(xml_file) as xml:
    r = requests.post(api_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"}, data=xml)

print(r.content)
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CreateOrUpdateTaskRequest xmlns="Trackem.Web.Services">
<UserName>h1234</UserName>
<Password>1234</Password>
<Operation>Create</Operation>
<TaskNumber>393874939</TaskNumber>
<EmployeeNumber>cd123</EmployeeNumber>
<DueDateAsSecondsFromEpoch>20210527130000</DueDateAsSecondsFromEpoch>
<DueDateAsYYYYMMDDHHMMSS>20210527130000</DueDateAsYYYYMMDDHHMMSS>
<Notes>Pycharm</Notes>
<Description>Pycharm Test</Description>
<Status>DontChange</Status>
<Address>Calle 61</Address>
<City>Miami</City>
<Street>Calle 59</Street>
<HouseNumber>8</HouseNumber>
</CreateOrUpdateTaskRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas why this request works in SOAPUI-5.6.0 but not in Pycharm? Right now the error I am getting is"Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action." But that is just one of many error I have been trying to trouble shoot. I can't figure why this works in SOAPUI but not in Pycharm. Any ideas?

Comment: Try with this: add `?WSDL` to the end of your url.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using Zeeps library, this error is because you are not sending the headers with the request.